# How to include a dll for publish in Visual Studio

Tags: publishing

The project uses Helix publishing and all the Sitecore dlls are excluded, in the publishing targets file.

```
  <ItemGroup>        
    <SitecoreAssembliesToExclude Include="@(SitecoreAssemblies)" />        
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Sitecore.*.dll" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.dll.config" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.pdb" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Scriban.dll;bin\Spatial4n.Core.dll;bin\Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll;bin\Microsoft.OData.Client.dll;bin\AjaxMin.dll;bin\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.dll" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="bin\de" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
```

But I want to include this dll - `Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy`

How to do that

Comment: Have you considered putting this dll as a package in release pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute `Exclude` that should works for you. You can add `Exclude="Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.dll"` to the corresponding `ExcludeFromPackageFiles` node.

```
  <ItemGroup>        
    <SitecoreAssembliesToExclude Include="@(SitecoreAssemblies)" />        
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Sitecore.*.dll" Exclude="Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.dll" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.dll.config" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.pdb" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Scriban.dll;bin\Spatial4n.Core.dll;bin\Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll;bin\Microsoft.OData.Client.dll;bin\AjaxMin.dll;bin\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.dll" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="bin\de" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried `Exclude="Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.dll"` & `Exclude="bin\Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.dll"`. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSV file and mentioned all the DLL into that file like below:

[image]

I have created one folder named `AssemblyLists` and put the CSV files under this and mentioned all the DLL which I want to exclude.

After that write the below code into the `publishing targets file` i.e. `Deploy.wpp.targets`:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <!-- Exclude Sitecore Assemblies -->
        <SitecoreAssemblyListsToExclude Include="AssemblyLists\*.csv" />

        <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Sitecore.*.dll" />
        <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.dll.config" />
        <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\*.pdb" />
        <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="bin\Scriban.dll;bin\Spatial4n.Core.dll;bin\Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll;bin\Microsoft.OData.Client.dll;bin\AjaxMin.dll;bin\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.dll" />
        <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="bin\de" />

</ItemGroup>
```

Here I have used **`SitecoreAssemblyListsToExclude`** instead of **`SitecoreAssembliesToExclude`**.